# WSO2 ESB: empty fields ("") are added as null and I can't make them stay as empty string

Tags: json, wso2, wso2-esb

Good afternoon, I am working with the WSO2 EI and I have a problem, I am receiving a json payload and I need to pass these parameters as they come to a WebService that I call, however, I get that the empty fields are being passed as null and not as empty strings "", then I would like to know if there is a possibility to change that option, from null to ""

My Payload Json

```
{  
        "channel": "external",  
        "domain": "auth", 
        "serviceName": "serviceToken",    
        "payload": {    
            "audit": {  
                "operationId": 0,   
                "userId": "0000000",  
                "applicationId": 76,    
                "operationDate": "2017-08-22T07:50:00-04:00",   
                "nodeName": "10.10.10.10"   
            },  
            "customer":{    
              "documentType" : "",
              "documentNumber" : "123456879"    
                    },  
            "authorizationInfo": {  
                    "otp":"000000"   
        }   
       }    
    }
```

> payload =
> {"channel":"external","domain":"auth","serviceName":"service","payload":{"audit":{"operationId":0,"userId":0000000,"applicationId":76,"operationDate":"2017-08-22T07:50:00-04:00","nodeName":"10.10.10.10"},"customer":{"**documentType":null**,"documentNumber":12345897},"authorizationInfo":{"otp":0000000}}}

I wish it really showed like this: **documentType":"",**

Answer (score 1):

You can try change synapse engine settings. According to this documentation: [Handling XML to JSON conversion - Empty XML elements](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Working+with+JSON+Message+Payloads#WorkingwithJSONMessagePayloads-EmptyXMLelements), try set in config file: *synapse.properties* : `synapse.commons.enableXmlNullForEmptyElement=false`

WSO2 products underneath works on XML, even you just print out JSON, so this setting is worth a shot.

Comment: I can vouch for this setting, using it as well.